# Problem with the return value in function

Tags: c, return, return-value

I'm trying to tackle this task: Write a function `int *dec2bin(int N, int *n)` that calculates and returns a binary representation for a natural number 0 ≤ N < 65535 and returns the binary representation. It holds that n ≤ 16. The function returns the binary representation of `N` without leading zeros. Note that also the length of the vector is "must be returned". For example, the function for `N = 77` returns the vector `1 0 0 1 1 0 1` back. Furthermore, write a calling `main` program in which `N` is read in and the corresponding binary representation is output.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *dec2bin(int N, int *n);

int main() {
    int N;
    int n[16];
    
    do {
        printf("\n input:");
        scanf("%d", &N);
    } while (N < 0 || N > 65535);
    dec2bin (N, n);
    
    printf("&d has the binary value %d", N, *n);
}

int *dec2bin(int N, int *n) {
  for (int i = 0; N > 0; i++) {    
      n[i] = N % 2;
      N /= 2;
   }
   return n[i];
}
```

Problem:
The compiler tells me that `return n[i]` is undeclared. I tried loads of things but that made just more problems, help much appreciated

Comment: Where is `i` declared?  Where does its lifetime end?

Comment: isn't it enough that i declared it in the for function?

Comment: declare `i` outside `for` loop in fn: `int* dec2bin`

Comment: If I do this the compiler tells me "returnig 'int' from a function with return type 'int *' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
return n[i]

Comment: @kilston That error has nothing to do with `i`.

Comment: You throw away the function result anyway, so why bother returning anything?

Comment: `"without leading zeros"`... So, 2 should be `10`, not `0...10`... What do you expect to print if the input decimal value is `0`? Seems you'll want to output the value of the LSB, regardless...

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
int* dec2bin(int N, int* n){
    
      for(int i=0;N>0;i++){    
      n[i] = N % 2;
      N /= 2;
   }
   return n[i];
}
```

the variable `i` is out-of-scope in the

```
   return n[i];
```

statement as it ceases to exist when the `for` loop ends.

Per [**6.8.5.3 The for statement**, paragraph 1 of the (draft) C11 standard](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.5.3p1)(bolding mine):

> The statement
>
> ```
>       for ( clause-1 ; expression-2 ; expression-3 ) statement
> ```
>
> behaves as follows: The expression expression-2 is the controlling
> expression that is evaluated before each execution of the loop body.
> The expression expression-3 is evaluated as a void expression after
> each execution of the loop body. **If clause-1 is a declaration, the
> scope of any identifiers it declares is the remainder of the
> declaration and the entire loop, including the other two expressions**;
> it is reached in the order of execution before the first evaluation of
> the controlling expression. If clause-1 is an expression, it is
> evaluated as a void expression before the first evaluation of the
> controlling expression.

You need to declare `i` *before* the loop:

```
int dec2bin(int N, int* n){
      int i;
      for(i=0;N>0;i++){    
      n[i] = N % 2;
      N /= 2;
   }
   return n[i];
}
```

Also, `int* dec2bin()` means `dec2bin()` returns a pointer to an `int` but `n[i]` (were `i` in scope) would be an `int`, not a pointer to an `int`.  I changed the code to return `int` instead of `int *`.  That might not be appropriate.

Comment: Please note that the problem statement in the question is so ambiguous that `n` might be the actual length of the binary representation and the returned `int *` might point to the "vector" (allocated in the function?).

Comment: @AndrewHenle is it somehow possible  instead of changing the dec2bin() function to a non pointer to just change the return to a pointer. I'm guessing n+i might work...pointer arithmetic

Answer (score 0):

The problem description is somewhat ambiguous.  One possible interpretation is the function `dec2bin` should allocate an array of `int`, populate it with the binary representation of `N` from the most significant to the least significant bit, without leading zeroes. The length of this array should be stored to `*n` and a pointer to the array should be returned to the caller.

In your code, you should define `n` as an `int` and pass its address and define a pointer to `int` to store the return value of `dec2bin`.

The compiler complains that *`return n[i]` is undeclared* because the variable `i` defined in the initial clause of the `for` loop is unavailable after the end of the loop.  You should just `return p` anyway and store `*n = i` to provide the array length to the caller.

Here is a modified version that reflects this interpretation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// convert N to an array of bits, store the length to *n
int *dec2bin(int N, int *n);

int main(void) {
    int N;
    int *p; // pointer to the allocated array
    int n;  // length of the array
    
    do {
        printf("\n input:");
        if (scanf("%d", &N) != 1) {
            printf("invalid input\n");
            return 1;
        }
    } while (N < 0 || N > 65535);

    p = dec2bin(N, &n);

    if (p == NULL) {
        printf("conversion of %d failed\n", N);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("%d has the binary value ", N);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d", p[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    free(p);
    return 0;
}

int *dec2bin(int N, int *n) {
    // use unsigned arithmetics and limit to 16 bits
    unsigned int u = N & 0xFFFF;
    int bits[16];
    int i;

    /* compute the bits from least significant to most significant */
    for (i = 0;;) {
         bits[i++] = u & 1;
         u = u >> 1;
         if (u == 0) {
             // stop when all significant bits have been stored
             break;
         }
    }
    // allocate the array
    int *p = malloc(sizeof(int) * i);
    if (p != NULL) {
        // store the bits from most significant to least significant
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            p[j] = bits[i - j - 1];
    }
    // "return" the array length and the array pointer
    *n = i;
    return p;
}
```

Note that `dec2bin` is a misnomer because the argument `N` is not really *decimal*.

Comment: @Bob__: I agree with your assessment: *Please note that the problem statement in the question is so ambiguous that `n` might be the actual length of the binary representation and the returned `int *` might point to the "vector" (allocated in the function?).*