# The program has no syntax error however no result comes out

Tags: c, function, printf

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *dec2bin(int N, int *n);

int *dec2bin(int N, int *n) {
    int l = 0;
    do {
        if (N % 2 == 0) {
            n[l] = 0;
            l++;
        } else {
            n[l] = 1;
            l++;
        }
        N = N / 2;
    } while (N != 0);
    return n;
}

int main() {
    int N = 0;
    int *n = NULL;
    
    n = malloc(sizeof(int));
    do {
        printf("type an integer\n");
        scanf("%d", &N);
    } while (N <= 0 || N > 65535);
    
    n = dec2bin(N, n);
    
    int l = n[0];
    printf("the binary equivalent of %d is: ", N);
    n = realloc(n, (l + 1) * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = l; i >= 1; i--) {
        printf("%d", n[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the program should spit out the binary number of an integer number:

My problem is that the program compiles but the `printf` in the `main` function does not work I think or it's the `dec2bin` that has a problem but I think it has more to do with the `printf`.

I tried so much. Asking chat gpt for an hour, also trying out what might be wrong by myself for hours but I just couldn't find the mistake. That's the reason for me posting this question

Comment: You cannot allocate space for just one `int`, then assign values to multiple elements, then use `realloc` to request space for the elements you already tried to assign. You need to redesign your code to have space for each element before you try to assign a value to that element.

Comment: Don't waste your time on ChatGPT! It doesn't "know" anything!

Comment: Your array-printing code doesn't know how many bits to print.  You're trying to set `int l = n[0]`, but you really need the last value that `l` in `dec2bin` had.

Comment: Side point, to keep in mind:  Oftentimes, writing code that compiles without error is the easy part, while rooting out the remaining logic errors — that is, debugging — is the hard part!  So saying "the program compiles but does not work" doesn't mean much.

Comment: @EricPostpischil but how do I know how much space is need before assigning the value. I was also thinking about that but i didnt come up with something. Do you have an idea?

Comment: @kilston: If you current have space for x elements, and you are about to write the element with index y, then you need space for y+1 elements (from index 0 to index y, inclusive, is y+1 elements). If x ≤ y+1, then you hae enough. Otherwise, you need to allocate more.

Comment: I made these changes to your program: (1) `n=malloc(30);`, (2) have `dec2bin` return `l`, (3) in `main`, set `l` to `dec2bin`'s return value, (4) get rid of `realloc` call, and (5) change the digit-printing loop to run from `l-1` down to 0.  The program seems to be printing good results for me.  So you're close!

Comment: BTW, you don't need that array at all. You can just print the bits as soon as are calculated.

Comment: @EricPostpischil but for example in my code with the code line malloc... i have only space for one bit apparently but how do I know the amout of bits of the integer number which would be the y in your proposition?

Comment: @SteveSummit is the 30 in malloc(30) random or what did you think?

Comment: Also note that you can know *at compile time* how many bits are there in an `int`.

Comment: @kilston That was pretty random, yeah.  I spent no time on it.  A better choice would be `malloc(8 * sizeof(int))`, and an even better one might be `malloc(CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int))`.  Although since you limit N to 65535, obviously 16 would be enough.

Comment: @SteveSummit another thing you are mentioning at point (2) to return l. however the function should return a pointer integer *int but l is an integer, so that doesn't work. What do you think of that?

Comment: @kilston "The function should return a pointer."  Is that what your instructor told you?  Obviously I ignored that requirement.  There are lots of ways of attacking this problem, and having `dec2bin` return `int l` is just one of them.  (It's not really even the best way, but it's the shortest putt from where you started, so to speak.)

Comment: Is it supposed to return a pointer to `int`?  Or could it return a pointer to `char`?

Comment: @SteveSummit it supposed to return a pointer to int. So that doesn't work. Does something else pop into your mind? And yeah the function with the return value was given so one cannot change the function

Comment: Idea #1: do what I suggested, and at least get it working.  Having code that works is incredibly satisfying, and it ought to get you at least partial credit.  Idea #2: have `dec2bin` always fill in 16 bits (that is, don't stop when `N == 0`), and in `main`, always print 16 bits.  Idea #3: use an extra pointer-to-`int` parameter to `dec2bin` by which it can additionally return ("by reference") the number of digits it generated (i.e., the value of `l`).  Idea #4: explicitly return the value of `l` in `n[0]`, and then be careful not to print it (which might have been what you were trying to do).

Comment: If "the function with the return value was given", you probably can't use idea #3.  But good luck!  I think you're almost there.

Answer (score 1):

The problem description is absent from the question, but from your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74721794/problem-with-the-return-value-in-function), it seems the function `dec2bin` is expected to allocate an array of `int`, populate it with the binary representation of `N` from the most significant to the least significant bit, without leading zeroes. The length of the array should be stored to `*n` and a pointer to the array should be returned to the caller.

In your code, you should define `n` as an `int` and just pass its address and define a pointer to `int` to store the return value of `dec2bin`.

Using the type `unsigned int` is recommended to avoid surprising results on negative values. Masking the value with `0xFFFF` ensures that only 16 bits are processed.

Here is a modified version that reflects this interpretation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// convert N to an array of bits, store the length to *n
int *dec2bin(int N, int *n);

int main(void) {
    int N;
    int *p; // pointer to the allocated array
    int n;  // length of the array
    
    do {
        printf("\n input:");
        if (scanf("%d", &N) != 1) {
            printf("invalid input\n");
            return 1;
        }
    } while (N < 0 || N > 65535);

    p = dec2bin(N, &n);
    
    if (p == NULL) {
        printf("conversion of %d failed\n", N);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("%d has the binary value ", N);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d", p[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    free(p);
    return 0;
}

int *dec2bin(int N, int *n) {
    // use unsigned arithmetics and limit to 16 bits
    unsigned int u = N & 0xFFFF;
    int bits[16];
    int i;

    /* compute the bits from least significant to most significant */
    for (i = 0;;) {
         bits[i++] = u & 1;
         u = u >> 1;
         if (u == 0) {
             // stop when all significant bits have been stored
             break;
         }
    }
    // allocate the array
    int *p = malloc(sizeof(int) * i);
    if (p != NULL) {
        // store the bits from most significant to least significant
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            p[j] = bits[i - j - 1];
    }
    // "return" the array length and the array pointer
    *n = i;
    return p;
}
```

Note that `dec2bin` is a misnomer because the argument `N` is not really *decimal*.

Comment: @SteveSummit: OK, thanks for pointing this.  I wish teachers would grow wiser and give students more consistent assignments.  The very name `dec2bin` is telling: `N` is not a *decimal* number, it is just an integer and the internal representation must be binary anyway.

Comment: Based on a previous question (SO question 74721794) it appears that the pointer being returned from the dec2bin function is to be used to suppress any leading zeroes in the final output.

Comment: @HaveCompiler--WillTravel Good grief.  [Nice find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74721794).  What a bizarre API!  It makes for some stupidly fussy code in the caller, having to basically compute `16 - (n - r)`.  Like chqrlie, I wish teachers would give better assignments than this, too (but I'm not holding my breath).

Comment: @SteveSummit: I think I nailed it: the function allocates an array, converts `N` to its binary bits into the array without leading zeroes and in MSB to LSB order, stores the length to `*n` and returns a pointer to the array.  That's a more consistent API, but it was poorly explained in the [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74721794/4593267).

Answer (score 0):

Using your code, with some slight adjustments.

I believe this solution is in line with the original question using the n-array to hold the length of the stored bits.

- placed the reallocate in the function dec2bin, where the array should be expanded.
- used first element n[0] to store the length of the array used for the storing of the bits.
- in the main print loop use the n[0] content as the strarting element to print, not printing the n[0] itself.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int *dec2bin(int N, int *n) {
  int l = 1;
  do {
    n = realloc(n, (l + 1) * sizeof(int));   // expand n array
    if (N % 2 == 0) {
      n[l] = 0;
      l++;
    } else {
      n[l] = 1;
      l++;
    }
    N = N / 2;
  } while (N != 0);
   n[0]=l-1; // #bits stored here
  return n;
}

int main() {
  int N = 0;
  int *n = NULL;

  n = malloc(sizeof(int));
  do {
    printf("type an integer\n");
    scanf("%d", &N);
  } while (N <= 0 || N > 65535);

  n = dec2bin(N, n);

  for (int i = n[0] ; i > 0; i--) {
    printf("%d", n[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Good Luck

Comment: I will update the answer, in line with the comments above and the OP remark about keeping the original function call definition.

Comment: Furthermore, a code-dump is not all that helpful.  Better would be to fully *explain* the answer so that it is useful and helpful to future visitors who come to this site looking for solutions to similar problems, since after all, this is the whole purpose of the site. The [answer] link can help guide you with suggestions on how to improve this and your future answers.

Comment: Returning an array whose first entry is the number of elements is such an ugly convention... Somewhat consistent with the OP's code and the imposed API.

Comment: @S_IROTH I don't understand the "n[0]=l-1" line. Why l-1? Why not just n[0]=l ? could you please explain this

Comment: @kilston If you work through the index arithmetic, you'll see it has to be that way, and doesn't work if you use `n[0]=l`.  There are two things going on: (1) If an n-element array starts with index 0 (as of course all arrays do in C), the highest element is at index `n-1`, not `n`. But (2) in *this particular* (rather strange) array, there are actually n+1 elements, one for the count.  So you need some ±1 fudge factors somewhere.  S_IROTH chose to put a fudge factor where a value was put in to `n[0]`, but it would also have been possible to do it not there, but later in the printing loop.

Comment: @kilston There are two different take-home lessons here. (1) So-called "fencepost errors" do come up a lot in programming, and you have to learn to be very careful in dealing with them.  But (2) one way of dealing with them is by avoiding them, not looking for ways to make them even even more prevalent and confusing.  So an array with n+1 elements, where the [0] element is a count giving the size of the rest of the array, is a confusing and not very good data structure.  All in all this is a terrible way of writing a binary converter.  (Not your fault: your lame instructor forced it on you.)